# How to create a multi-series stacked bar chart in dc.js

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, dc.js, stacked-chart

My needs are very similar to those of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016970/multi-series-line-chart-in-dc-js/19021429), where a series of records like:

```
var data = [
 // time, text, temperature, count
 ['1379952000', 'field_1', 91, 56],
 ['1379952000', 'field_2', 50, 20],
 ['1379952000', 'field_3', 88, 24],
 ['1379952000', 'field_4', 50, 37],
 ['1379953200', 'field_1', 97, 58],
 ['1379953200', 'field_2', 84, 86],
 ['1379953200', 'field_3', 85, 62],
 ['1379953200', 'field_4', 88, 73]
 // etc.
];
```

Need to be plotted as a set of time series **lines**, each series corresponding to each unique value of the `text` field (i.e. `field_1`, `field_2`, etc.). A working possible implementation was given in the answer to that question [here](http://bl.ocks.org/jrideout/6710590). However, I need the series to be plotted as **bars**.

I figured I should check how is dc.js's `seriesChart` class implemented and try to fork it to use `barChart` instead of `lineChart` as its internal plotting function. You can find [the result here](http://bl.ocks.org/lulingar/8268767). (See the file `seriesbarchart.js` and compare to [the source](https://github.com/NickQiZhu/dc.js/blob/master/src/series-chart.js?source=cc))

The one flaw my test has is the single-pixel width the bars come out with. I'm a newbie to this Web world of Javascript/HTML/CSS and even more so about D3 and dc.js. Can somebody knowledgeable give me a hand with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the xUnits to be a time interval, such as minutes or hours:

```
time_chart
.xUnits(d3.time.minutes)
```

For your data, however, you probably want a 15 minute time interval.  This would require a custom time interval.

Here is a question that addresses that:
  [How to define custom time interval in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276173/how-to-define-custom-time-interval-in-d3-js)

Comment: This worked, after having to add a line to the source `d3.js` in order to expose the `d3_time_interval` class, so that I could define a custom time unit in a way identical to that of `d3.time.minute`. Would you have a less "hacky" way of achieving this?

Comment: Hi Luis, I suppose you could redefine this class on your own. could you share your solution for future viewers of this thread?